# how to add subgraph with (new nodes, new edges) to an existed graph in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to add new nodes (red dots) with new edges (green lines) to be places diagonaly
new color and positions to this grid graph [image: Graph]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5, 5])

nodes = list(G.nodes)
edges = list(G.edges)

p = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(0, 5):
        p.append([i, j])


for i in range(0, len(nodes)):
    G.nodes[nodes[i]]['pos'] = p[i]

pos = {}
for i in range(0, len(nodes)):
    pos[nodes[i]] = p[i]

nx.draw(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your question is not clear for me, but you can create list of edges and then use `G.add_edges_from()` to add nodes & edges to your initial graph

Probably you should define algorithm to find coordinates / labels of new nodes, then construct edges and add by `G.add_edges_from()`

```
G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5, 5])

new_edges = [((0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 2.5)),
             ((0.5, 1.5), (0, 2)),
             ((0.5, 2.5), (0, 2))]

G.add_edges_from(new_edges)

nx.draw(G, pos={n:n for n in G.nodes()})
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDITED**

I modified code:

- nodes are renamed and have 'coord' and 'color' attributes
- graph are drawn wrt color of node

Probably there is a better way to solve this problem cause code looks massive)

```
G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5, 5])

# rename nodes & set coord and color (0 - blue, 1 - red) attributes to nodes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {n: {"coord": n, "color": 0} for n in G.nodes()})
nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping={coord:label
                             for label,coord in zip(range(len(G)), G.nodes())}, copy=False)

# we are GIVEN list nodes & edges to add
new_nodes = [(label, {'coord': coord, 'color': 1})
             for label, coord in zip([26, 27], [(0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 2.5)])]
new_edges = [(2, 26), (2, 27), (26, 27)]

G.add_nodes_from(new_nodes)
G.add_edges_from(new_edges)

color_map = {0: '#7d99f5', 1: '#f57d7d'}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos={n:G.nodes[n]['coord'] for n in G.nodes()},
                 with_labels=True,
                 node_color=[color_map[n[1]['color']]
                             for n in G.nodes(data=True)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks I didn't know that I can put float values in a tuple, how to make the color of the only added nodes to change? like give attributes about the color and coordinate

Comment: I edited code and added 'coord' and 'color' attr to nodes)

Comment: thanks a lot :) can you please recommend a function to make graphs spatial

Comment: You can use `plotly` library. This [article](https://deepnote.com/@deepnote/3D-network-visualisations-using-plotly-a18c5e37-a517-4b27-bfde-1fee94a5760f) should help you)